# Incremental backups from Rackspace Cloud Files to Amazon Glacier

Tags: rackspace-cloud, incremental-backup, cloud-storage, amazon-glacier

Is there a software product/module (open-source or commercial) that can provide incremental backups from Rackspace Cloud Files to Amazon Glacier?

We are looking for something that will provide the following functionality (or achieve the same result, i.e. a cost-effective backup plan for files stored in Rackspace Cloud Files):

- Work out which files have been added to or modified in a Rackspace Cloud account (since the last backup).
- Create a ZIP (or similar) of these files and store them in Amazon Glacier.
- Keep a record of which files are in which ZIPs.
- Ideally, restore either a single file or all files from Glacier back into Rackspace.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq), and generally off topic [StackExchange wide](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/qa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [Cloud Migrator](http://sync.cloudberrylab.com/home.aspx) service by CloudBerry Lab. May become a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks - this is worth investigating further. The doco is a bit lacking. Do you know if this would enable incremental backups? It looks like it might just copy specified files and folders.

Comment: Ok, so it would allow us to do incremental backups (when creating a task there's a checkbox ‘Copy files changed since last sync only’). I'm going to accept as this service does answer my question. I would still be interested in knowing if there's anything open-source that does it though (with Cloud Migrator you pay per GB transferred and also per hour of CPU time used).